# Scheduler jobs Testing

Tags: testing, automated-tests, scheduled-tasks, integration-testing, scheduler

How do you test cron/lambda scheduler job in your project , is it through logs , expected behaviour , what level of testing unit , integrations etc  , or any automation tool which you use to test them.

I have tried logs checking and manual testing for the expected behaviours in the past.